# sharedApplication takes long to display

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, unity-game-engine, native-code

So I added some code to this to work on both ios 8 and 9(5s and ipad). Before the change the 5s would load the share dialog fairly quick while the ipad would crash the device.  After adding the fix they both don't crash, but now the ipad displays the share dialog fairly quick while the 5s takes roughly ~1-2 mins to display it.  Not sure why that might be, maybe I did something wrong with my change?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


extern "C" {
    void _shareText(const char *text, const char *imgUrl)
    {
        NSString * message = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:text];
        NSString * urlAddress = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:imgUrl];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

        NSMutableArray *sharingItems = [NSMutableArray new];

        if (text) {
            [sharingItems addObject:message];
        }
        if (img) {
            [sharingItems addObject:img];
        }
       UIViewController *qtController = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow rootViewController];
       UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharingItems applicationActivities:nil];


      if ([activityController respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverPresentationController)] ){
           [qtController presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
           activityController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = qtController.view;
      }else{
          [qtController presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
      } 
    }
}
```

Update:

Unity Called function:

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void _shareText(string message, string imgUrl);

    public static void InviteRequest(string message, string imgUrl)
    {
        #if UNITY_IOS
        if (Application.platform != RuntimePlatform.OSXEditor)
        {
            _shareText(message, imgUrl);
        }
        #endif
    }
```

Comment: Does that code run on the main thread?

Comment: its a plugin for a unity app.  Unity call look like the add to the question I added:

Comment: Added the entire plugin func being called

Comment: I don't know much about Unity plugins, but my gut feeling is that you're altering the UI from a background thread. The reason it takes 2 minutes to update is because that's about the length of time it takes for you to get fed up, tapping the screen and causing the UI to update and draw the new viewcontroller.

Comment: In your obj-c code, if you put a breakpoint in at the top and then in the debugger (if you're in Xcode), type `po [NSThread isMainThread]` it'll give you a definitive answer

Comment: I got a response of 0x0000000000000001